# Free Linux SFTP with per-user access to folders

Tags: gratis, linux, ftp, sftp

I am looking for a good free SFTP system for *nix. I need to be able to create accounts with segregated access to individual folders.

Here is the detail...

We currently have an FTP server which all the support engineers use very often to move files from DAD to the FTP server and visa versa. The cannot be copied directly from the RDP session. In addition to this the engineers drop files on the FTP server for clients to retrieve. Engineers also send config backups of their clients to the FTP server. As this is a client facing solution we as a security organisation cant be seen to be using a non secure protocol such as FTP.

There are many free flavours of SFTP which basically only allow you to send files over SFTP to the root folder on the SFTP server with full rights to the root folder. We require the ability to create files for clients with certain permissions that will for example allow a client to drop files on the server but not rename or delete them. In addition to this the client will only see his folder as opposed to all the other folders on the SFTP server based on his username and password.

Any ideas?

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you using? Are there any other features that would be nice to have?

Comment: Haven't' decided on a flavor yet, happy to go with anything , this will be purely dedicated for the FTP.

Comment: Hi Darren.  Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!  We hope you'll like the place and decide to stay.  Thanks for your question.  If I may ask:  Must you choose SFTP specifically?  What types of files will you be serving, and who will be retrieving the files?  What OS will your clients be using?  Will your clients be able to install [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) instead of an SFTP client?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and enlighten us.  The more information you provide, the better.  If you provide enough information and get enough upvotes, your question may be listed on the ["hot"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot) tab.

Comment: Hi all, Updated question

Comment: The permissions should be set on the server for each user, so I don't quite understand why the client matters that much.